# Manually creating master and slave in RDS

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services

I am running the MYSQL RDS DB running on MultiAZ. I am doing mysqldump every day to take the backup. The mysqldump will be done on master db, one of my friend asked to manually create the slave db. I am not sure how do I create a slave db manually any heads up?

Thanks a lot

Comment: [Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replication.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

First, if you a running a multi-AZ RDS, there is probably no reason whatsoever for you to be doing your own mysqldumps.

You can use automated RDS backups to do this for you, and they will actually be performed against the synchronously updated standby RDS so as to not require you to lock up your production database while doing a dump.  It also makes it much easier for you to restore your backup snapshot to an RDS instance.  This also saves you the output bandwidth cost on DB dump and input bandwidth cost on DB import.

As far as setting up a replica goes, if the intent is to be able to have a read-only slave, you can easily do this this via the console or command line tools, and again, the replica will be established from your standby RDS, so as to not disturb your production DB while the DB snapshot is being taken as the basis for the replica.